# Javascript regular expression is failing

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following javascript regex:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^" + term + ".*")
console.log(pattern.toSource());
console.log(first_name + " : " + pattern.test(first_name) );
```

All i want it to do is check if the first name of the person begins with the search term given. E.g if the search term is 'a', then all the first names starting with a, e.g: andy, alice, etc should match. If its al, then only alice should match, etc. However the output is:

```
/^a.*/
Alyssa : false
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, `A` is not the same as `a`... No need got the `.*`, btw. This will do: `var pattern = /^a/i;` or `var pattern = /^[aA]/;`

Comment: incorrect question title - the regexp is doing exactly what it was told to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong, you should make the RegExp case insensitive using

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^" + term + ".*","i")
```

to match your name as long you want to render the test case insensitive or use a match like `/^[aA].*/`

Answer (score 2):

Regexs are case-sensitive. So `Alyssa` won't match, because `A` and `a` are different symbols.
You may want to use case-insensitive regex match:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^" + term + ".*", "i")
console.log(pattern.toSource());
console.log(first_name + " : " + pattern.test(first_name) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could specify your RegEx to be case insensitive, so that `a` will match both `a` and `A`:

```
 var pattern = new RegExp("^" + term + ".*", "i");
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your `RegExp` case insensitive:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^" + term + ".*", "i");
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp).

Answer (score 1):

your regex is *case sensitive* so it's not matching Alyssa add this line to your code:

```
pattern.ignoreCase = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it isn't working is that regular expressions are case sensitive. `A` is not `a`

Other things you are doing wrong:

- Bothering to say "Followed by zero or more characters", that is just redundant.
- Using a regular expression when a simple substring check will do the job.

I'd do it like this:

```
console.log(
    first_name + " : " + 
    (first_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) === 0)
);
```

Comment: Regexps are faster than substring, aren't they? Also, `indexOf` will return true if the string is found anywhere in the string as compared to just in the beginning, won't it?

Comment: It seems unlikely, especially if the regex has to be dynamically constructed. I'd have to benchmark it to be sure. And no, `indexOf` never returns `true` or `false`. If it returns `0` (which is what my example checks for) then it has found at match at index 0, which is the first character.